# How sprites works in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have a scene with a lot of sprites and pretty bad frame rate. I was trying reducing sprites resolution, setting camera limitation to render distance, but to no avail. There is two another ways: creating plates that faces camera or particle system, but this sprites use a lot of textures so this methods will call a lot of draw calls(for every texture). So can u explain when and how sprites are draw on the scene, how they use draw calls and may be there are any performance trick?

i have around 2500 sprites with 200 textures(256x256).

Sorry for duplication my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307022/render-a-big-number-of-sprites?noredirect=1#comment87630749_50307022), but I can not believe that sprites works so bad in three.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render a big number of sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307022/render-a-big-number-of-sprites)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprites are drawn the same way as everything else, they’re just quads which rotate to face the camera.

With three, make sure you’re not recreating the same object - material, texture, whatever - when you could have made one and reused it.

I think the problem might be the high number of different textures. It might be better to use a texture atlas.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! About texture atlas. It should be used with sprites or PlaneGeometries? As i understand for sprites it's only available choosing parts of texture atlas by texture.repeat and texture.offset, this needs to have separate material for every part and doesnt save draw calls. For planes there could be used uv mapping, but i dont properly understand how to make it in one call, if i'll merge all planes, I will not have the opportunity to rotate everyone of them to camera

Comment: Good points. Yeah it is weird that you have to make new materials to change texture offset and repeat. It might be optimised though, I would test it. If you want to try making planes behave like sprites, look up 'billboard matrix'. I think it's possible in theory to do it with one merged geometry, but you'd have to do all the rotations in the vertex shader.

Comment: Thanks, i ll try it, i was thinking about using particle system and ShaderMaterial(i have tested, and its perfectly draws around 200k sprites, also it automatically rotates sprites to camera), but i found that i'm pretty bad with shaders to use uv mapping in it